# ¿Cómo evitar un ataque GET de este tipo que convierte la web en un enlace a un video youtube?

Tags: php, seguridad, hack

Han añadido esto (sguido a la url del dominio) y se convierte en un enlace a un video de youtube. ¿Cómo evitarlo?

**www.ejemplo.com/registrarForm.php?msg=%3Csvg%2Fonload%3Deval(atob(%27d2luZG93LmxvY2F0aW9uPSdodHRwczovL3d3dy55b3V0dWJlLmNvbS93YXRjaD92PWRRdzR3OVdnWGNRJwo%3D%27))%3E**

Realmente no es modificada la web original, pero se convierte en un enlace que podría ejecutarse cualquier cosa, incluso un script javascript. ¿Cómo evitarlo?

El form es el siguiente:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="insertarRegistroUsuario.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) { echo $_GET['msg']; } ?>

      <input type="text" id="nombreusuarioUsuario" name="nombreusuarioUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required autofocus>

      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="emailusuario" name="emailUsuario" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>

      <input type="password" id="passwordUsuario" name="passwordUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

      <input type="password" id="passwordUsuario2" name="passwordUsuario2" class="form-control" placeholder="Repetir Password" required>

      <input type="text" id="localidadUsuario" name="localidadUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Localidad" required autofocus>

      <input type="text" id="codigoPostalUsuario" name="codigoPostalUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo Potal" required autofocus>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Confirmar</button>

    </form>
```

También me han "atacado" de esta manera (sin modificarse la web original):

```
www.ejemplo.com/registrarseForm.php?msg=<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/ceblog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/22110359/youve-been-hacked.png" />
```

Comment: Si te añaden algo a las páginas será que han hackeado el sistema, deberías dar información sobre el backend usado ¿es una aplicación propia? ¿es un joomla, wordpress u otro cms? ¿es estándar o has realizado modificaciones/plugins propios? ¿que plugins tienes instalados? ¿que panel de control usas? cuanta más información mejor e indica que versiones ¿has actualizado modificado algo ultimamente?

Comment: El problema no es el enlace, sino lo que uno permite al recibir los datos por el método get,

Comment: `<?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) { echo $_GET['msg']; } ?>` esa linea escribe el svg con javascript que realiza la redirección, tendrías que sanitizar `msg` antes de imprimirlo

Comment: @aloMalbarez ni *saneado*, una línea así no tiene sentido más que para depurar, una web publicada no debería contener semejante agujero de seguridad.

Comment: ¿Solución? ¿Alternativa? el msg es para cuando hay un error, se devuelva por get, si hay un get, que lo imprima.

Comment: alternativas hay varias, desde donde se genera el `msg` ? es necesario que sea por `$_GET`? son mensajes predefinidos? de que dependen?

Comment: Da igual que sea `GET` o `POST`, debemos pensar que podría hacer un bot no un humano intentando hacer un ataque desde iexplorer.

Comment: @Fly justamente estoy pensando en un bot que pueda fakear toda la petición, pero sin mas datos de cómo refactorizar el asunto es ir adivinando. Para esto estan los comentarios, para pedir mas información.

Comment: @aloMalbarez no lo tomes a mal, fue un comentario para recalcar que es indiferente el método usado no porque fuera una pregunta fuera de lugar. Esta bien hacer preguntas amplias cuando el OP da tan poca información ;)

Comment: @Fly no me lo tomo a mal, `POST` no es la única alternativa que se puede implementar por eso pregunto si es necesario que sea `GET` (por cuestiones de logs o analytics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es controlar exactamente que se va a mostrar en pantalla, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    if ($_GET['msg'] == 'error') {
        switch ($_GET['code']) {
            case '001': $error = 'Error de la trocola del cigüeñal';
                break;
            case '002': $error = 'Error de usuario reincidente';
                break;
            default:
                $error = 'Error desconocido, salga y vuelva a entrar';
                break;
        }

        echo '<div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

A medida que hagas más compleja la programación delegarás la impresión de errores a una rutina específica, que hará algo más que sacar el mensaje a pantalla (escribir el error en el log, por ejemplo) pero mientras tanto, con no sacar el texto tal cual es más que suficiente.

En este pequeño ejemplo se usan un par de parámetros para decirle al script que debe sacar por pantalla en caso de error, pero podría ser cualquier cosa que necesites.

Ten en cuenta que al usuario tampoco le hace falta demasiada información técnica, por ejemplo, no saques consultas `sql` por pantalla, que lo único que facilita es dar pistas a un posible ataque intencionado.

Los datos técnicos sácalos a un log y por pantalla indica solo algo que al usuario le pueda servir (y que entienda): 'Inténtelo más tarde', 'Póngase en contacto', 'No use caracteres especiales'....

**NOTA**

> Para el log es suficiente con la instrucción
>   [php_log()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php)  y puedes
>   tener tus mensajes de error personalizados junto al los errores de
>   php o, si se lo indicas, tenerlos en un fichero independiente.

**TRUCO**

> Una cosa que se puede hacer para facilitar la depuración en producción
>   (por si no se quiere o no se puede tener el log visible en tiempo real), es
>   validar previamente al usuario logueado y si es un "administrador" se
>   podría sacar por pantalla información de sensible, como consultas sql,
>   valores de variables de sesión o volcados de objetos.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer uso de una función en `PHP` llamada `htmlspecialchars`. Puedes encontrar más referencias en este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp).

Lo que esta función hace es escapar el `HTML` a entidades, de esta manera cualquier tipo de código, ya sea Javascript o HTML, no se ejecutará.

Lo puedes usar en tu código como:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['msg']);
```

Answer (score 0):

yo hace un tiempo desarrolle una función en php lo que hace es sanizar un string de php quitando etiquetas **html** ataques mysql iframes y muchos otros.

existe strip_tag en php pero no es muy segura ya que exiten miles de maneras de encapsular un fragmento de código malicioso y insertarlo.

ej uso

$msj = ' " 
  **negrita**  alert("hacked"); ';
echo clear_data($msj);

resultado: **negrita-hacked**
solo devuelve texto si se trata de un script form strong lo eleminara

**funcion**

```
function clear_data($string, $force_lowercase=true,$anal=false){
$strip = array("~", "`", "!", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]", "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;", "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ">", "/", "?", "<form>", "href", "alert", "()", 'applet', 'body', 'bgsound', 'base', 'basefont', 'embed', 'frame', 'frameset', 'head', 'html', 'id', 'iframe', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'name', 'object', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'xml');
$clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
$clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
$clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean;
return ($force_lowercase) ?
(function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
strtolower($clean) :
$clean;
}
```